# Getting records from MySQL based on a time window

Tags: mysql, datetime

I want to count records based on a cut-off time. My cut-off time is midnight.

So, when a user inserts a new record, I want to know how many records have been inserted between NOW() and my cut-off time (which would be 12:00AM today). I don't know to tell MySQL to dynamically go 12:00AM of today... basically, what I want to do is:

`SELECT COUNT(id) FROM myTable WHERE createdAt is between now and today's 12:00AM`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A query like this should do the trick.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM myTable WHERE createdAt >= DATE(NOW()) AND createdAt <= NOW();
```

or simply

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM myTable WHERE createdAt >= DATE(NOW());
```

if you don't expect to have any records with createdAt date in the future.  You can also use the "Between" operator as so.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM myTable WHERE createdAt BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) AND NOW();
```

Comment: `CURDATE()` or `CURRENT_DATE()` will also work instead of `DATE(NOW())`.  And you can cast it to `DATETIME` if you want, although it shouldn't be needed for comparisons.